# apt-get update Kali Linux error

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade, error-handling

I tried updating with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
as well as with `apt-get update --fix-missing` and
`apt apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` but it always fails.
Whenever I type in `apt-get update`, I get the following error:

```
apt-get update
Get:1 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:1 http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/kali kali-rolling InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Hit:2 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease  
Reading package lists... Done   
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does the invalid signature `EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6` mean and how could I make it valid?

Is there any way to fix this so that I can update the repositories properly?
Your help would be appreciated a lot!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rui, if there's a direct duplicate to a Q, let's use that one (expkeysig)

Comment: @jeff Schaller, doesn't it seem obvious this community doesn't want to deal with kali... Lol just look at how these are being handled, it's deplorable. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117173/ask-kali

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
 wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add
```